# Is there a simple (permissive license) Leonardo driver for a USB-to-USART bridge to substitute an FTDI chip?

Tags: serial, usb, programmer

I'm making an ESP32 development board and I'm thinking about putting an Arduino Leonardo chip between the USB port and the ESP32's USART pins to act as a USB/USART converter instead of the FTDI chip so that I can program the ESP32 through a USB serial port like any other Arduino board.

Is there a library/sketch licensed under a permissive license (MIT, BSD, Apache, etc.) which can make the Leonardo chip act as a HID Serial Port device which has a device name I want for easy identification in Device Manager and which requires no special driver installation in Windows and Linux once plugged into the computer?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: you should do a better research before asking. "Leonardo chip"? "HID Serial port"? why do you wan't to use a 32u4 as USB-to-TTL-Serial? only Uno and Mega use an Atmel MCU for USB. most boards have FTDI or CH340 USB chips

Comment: @Juraj I use a small PIC32MX chip as a USB interface on my boards. I like the flexibility that creating your own interface gives you. For example, activating DTR on my system automatically creates a reset pulse, instead of just holding the line low.

Comment: The reason I'm using 32U4 is because I'd also like to use it as a virtual HID CD drive with a virtual CD providing an exe application for the end user to be able to upload firmware, communicate with the existing firmware, etc.. And most importantly, it's programmable as I want and all the code I add upon it is mine.

Answer (score 1):

Why not write your own?

First off, you'll want to create your own custom board definition. To do that, find the `boards.txt` file in the AVR core of your installation. Then find the block of entries that starts `leonardo.` and copy the whole block. Change the `leonardo` to a name of your choosing.

Then change the `.name` entry to give your board a new name in the IDE.

Finally look for the (renamed) entries:

```
leonardo.build.vid=0x2341
leonardo.build.pid=0x8036
leonardo.build.usb_product="Arduino Leonardo"
```

Of course the `leonardo` will be whatever you changed them to.  You can now give your board a new VID and PID to uniquely identify them - and also change the `usb_product` to name your board.

You can also add a `myboard.build.usb_manufacturer="..."` entry to change the manufacturer from the default of Arduino.

Now you have a board definition that identifies your board as what you want it to be.  So now just write a sketch that passes through the serial between USB and UART, and also handles the DTR and RTS signals to be able to enter flash mode on the ESP32 (hint: use `Serial.dtr()` and `Serial.rts()` to check the status of those signals).

Comment: That's quite a comprehensive response. Thank you! However, I still don't understand where's the HID Serial Port driver library (under a permissive license) for me to include in my C++ project and which functions/classes I need to use to talk to the USB side of things. I understand the Serial library, but that's for the USART between the Leonardo and the ESP32. I need the virtual USART part. Could you please append that to your answer?

Comment: It's already there. It's in the Arduino core. There is no library needed.

Comment: Oh, so there's Serial and Serial1? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Serial is the USB, and Serial1 is the TX/RX pins.